# splitting a string in Javascript into an array of embedded numbers

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to split a string into an array, where any numbers are split separately:

```
function mysplit(s) { ??? }

// What I want to have happen is this:
//
// mysplit('ABC12DEF678IJ') --> ['ABC',12,'DEF',678,'IJ']
// mysplit('ABCD123') --> ['ABCD',123]
// mysplit('Eeyore') --> ['Eeyore']
```

The only way I think I can do this is to use the function form of regex replace, using mutable state as the array, but that seems ugly. (See below TBD since that's the way I'm going to try to do it by default.)

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` can do it just fine:

```
function mysplit(s) {
    return s.match(/\d+|\D+/g);
}
```

[No tiny issue :)](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/ADJLV/)

Comment: ooh ahh, I think we have a winner (will accept once the timeout is done)

Comment: Ooh, I like it except that I have to convert the string numbers to numbers.

Comment: @JasonS: If you get to use the ES5 array extensions: `return s.match(/\d+|\D+/g).map(function(x) { var n = parseInt(x); return isNaN(n) ? x : n; });`

Answer (score 5):

Using **[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** itself but with separator retention.

```
'ABC12DEF678IJ'.split(/(\d+)/);
["ABC", "12", "DEF", "678", "IJ"]

'ABCD123'.split(/(\d+)/)
["ABCD", "123", ""] //tiny issue. ;)

'Eeyore'.split(/(\d+)/)
["Eeyore"]
```

If separator contains capturing parentheses, matched results are returned **in the array**.

Answer (score 1):

For reference here is my original approach, it doesn't look too bad:

```
function numsplit(s)
{
    var a = [];
    s.replace(/([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)/g, function(g) {
        a.push(isNaN(g) ? g : (+g));
    });
    return a;
}
```